# Including ListItem variables in JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a nested ListView (Master/Detail) and want to invoke a JavaScript function in the detail ItemTemplate so that this function can call a static method on the server site and post the field update. I need to include three data variables in the function call, two of which must come from the ListItem data. The JavaScript call to **SaveAnswer** that is contained in a list item embedded in the **inner** listview does not render properly. The code must pass three variables: **ThisPAQID** is a public variable from the codebehind. I could probably make it a hidden variable on this page. **QuestionID** is a variable from the current listitem and is contained in the table cell immediately preceeding the SaveAnswer method call.

The nested listview works great, and if I dummy the PAQID and QuestionID values in the function call (e.g. SaveAnswer(1,1, this.Value), it works fine.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstQuestions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lstQuestions_ItemDataBound">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 40px;" valign="top">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSectionCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SectionCode")%>' />.
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubsectionNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SubsectionNumber")%>' />
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"><%#Eval("SectionName")%></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"><%#Eval("SubsectionName")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">Q #</th>
      <th align="left">Question</th>
      <th align="left">Answer</th>
      <th align="left">Description / Scale</th>
    </tr>
    <asp:ListView ID="lstAnswers" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" OnItemDataBound="lstAnswers_ItemDataBound">
      <LayoutTemplate>
      <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
      </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;"><asp:Label ID="lblQuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>' /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><asp:Label ID="lblQuestionText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question")%>' /></td>
```

**Old Code:**

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Answer")%>' CssClass="DataEntry" MaxLength="3" Width="30px" onblur='SaveAnswer(<%#=Eval("ThisPAQID"%>,<%#=Eval("QuestionID"%>,this.value)' /></td>
```

**New Code:**

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Answer")%>' CssClass="DataEntry" MaxLength="3" Width="30px" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
    if (document.attachEvent) {
      document.attachEvent("onblur", textBox, function() {
        SaveAnswer('<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>', window.event.target.value);
      });
    } else {
      document.addEventListener("blur", textBox, function() {
        SaveAnswer('<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>', this.value);
      }, false);
    }
  </script>
</td>
```

**Rest of Code:**

```
    <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: -1;"><%#Eval("Description")%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-size: smaller; font-style: italic;"><%# Eval("ScaleText") %><br /><br /></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The generated code for the SaveAnswer now looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
    <span id="ctl00_body_lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_lblQuestionID">1</span>
  </td>
  <td style="vertical-align: top;"><span id="ctl00_body_lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_lblQuestionText">Written materials</span>
  </td>
  <td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <input name="ctl00$body$lstQuestions$ctrl0$lstAnswers$ctrl0$txtAnswer" type="text" value="2.0" maxlength="3" id="ctl00_body_lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_txtAnswer" class="DataEntry" style="width:30px;" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
    if (document.attachEvent) {
      document.attachEvent("onblur", textBox, function() {
        SaveAnswer('13242', '1', window.event.target.value);
      });
    } else {
      document.addEventListener("blur", textBox, function() {
        SaveAnswer('13242', '1', this.value);
      }, false);
    }
  </script>

  </td>
  <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: -1;">E.g., books, reports, office notes, articles, job instructions, or signs</td>
</tr>
```

When I put a breakpoint into this code in FireFox, the break never fires. Do I need an "OnBlur" tied to this code? Clearly I am not a JavaScript wizard.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your auto generated id is "ctl00_body_lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_txtAnswer" Which is Garbage + txtAnswer.

There are two ways to deal with it, either you think of something clever or use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

`var textBox = $("[id$='txtAnswer']");`

The easiest way to handle this is a little script tag

```
<script>
   var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
   if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onblur", textBox, function() {
             SaveAnswer(
                 '<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', 
                 '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>', 
                 window.event.target.value
             );
        });
   } else {
       document.addEventListener("blur", textBox, function() {
           SaveAnswer(
               '<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', 
               '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>', 
               this.value
           );
       }, false);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: That still won't help.  It's a server-side control.

Comment: @SLaks then I don't understand the question. I presume he wants to call the javascript `SaveAnswer` function with the static PAQID & static QuestionID from the server as well as the value from the client

Comment: @SLaks I see you can only use inline ASP like that in HTML!

Comment: I'm not used to doing event handling manually. Should have just done `$(textBox).blur(f);`

Comment: The PAQID value is constant for all list items. The QuestionID value changes with each instance of the list itme. txtAnswer contains the value that must be saved with QuestionID.

Comment: OK - so I am confused about where this text belongs. I have edited the original post so that you can see the entire definition of the control. Where to I stick you code?

Comment: @BobJones remove the `onBlur` line from your `<asp:textbox>` and insert the entire `<script>` block directly after `</asp:textbox>`

Comment: Thanks Raynow - I have incorporated your code (see above), but the JavaScript isn't firing yet.

Comment: Raynos - if you can help me over the last hump, I would appreciate it. And sorry for misspelling your name in my last comment post.

Comment: @BobJones I edited the answer to reflect that the id is auto generated. Use either a jQuery selector or find an alternative.