# Javascript code not being executed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a nested ListView (Master/Detail) questionaire that was described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823969/including-listitem-variables-in-javascript-function-call) posting: The inner list item must call a server method with three arguments. Thanks to several of you, I have code that properly generates the JavaScript; however, that code is not actually firing. Here is the declaration of the inner list view:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstAnswers" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" OnItemDataBound="lstAnswers_ItemDataBound">
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPAQID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ThisPAQID") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblPAQVersion" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PAQVersion") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>' />
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question")%>' />
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" Class="PAQAnswer" Text='<%#Eval("Answer")%>' />
              <script type="text/javascript">   **THIS SCRIPT IS NOT FIRING**
              var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
              if (document.attachEvent) {
                document.attachEvent("onblur", textBox, function() {
                  SaveAnswer('<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>',     window.event.target.value);
                });
              } else {
                document.addEventListener("blur", textBox, function() {
                  SaveAnswer('<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>', this.value);
                }, false);
              }   
            </script>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
<input name="lstQuestions$ctrl0$lstAnswers$ctrl0$txtAnswer" type="text" value="2.0" maxlength="3" id="lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_txtAnswer" Class="PAQAnswer" style="width:30px;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
  if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("onblur", textBox, function() {
      SaveAnswer('13242', '1', window.event.target.value);
    });
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("blur", textBox, function() {
      SaveAnswer('13242', '1', this.value);
    }, false);
  }   
</script>
```

The embedded values in the SaveAnswer calls are correct; however, I don't know how to tie the input statement to the JavaScript. Probably amazingly simple, but I don't see it... yet.

Comment: do `textBox.attachEvent` not `document.attachEvent` (also for addEventListener) (remove the textBox attribute from both too)

Answer (score 2):

this line looks like the problem:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
```

`txtAnswer` is not the actual ID of the control, so your script is not finding it. The ID of the input is `lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_txtAnswer`

You should try something like:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("<%= txtAnswer.ClientID %>");
```

which would translate to:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("lstQuestions_ctrl0_lstAnswers_ctrl0_txtAnswer");
```

**EDIT:** Why not do this instead?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" Class="PAQAnswer" Text='<%#Eval("Answer")%>' onBlur="SaveAnswer('<%#Eval("ThisPAQID")%>', '<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>', this.value);" />
```

Comment: When I try setting textBox = document.getElementById("<%=txtAnswer.ClientID %>", the compiler barfs and says "txtAnswer does not exist in the current context." What I did not show in the code is that lstAnswers is nested within another listview, so the id of ListView doesn't get defined until the ItemDataBound of the parent listview executes.

Comment: added a suggestion to the answer.

Comment: The edit doesn't work because "Code blocks are not supported in this context".

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the event like this:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
if (textBox.attachEvent) {
  textBox.attachEvent("onblur", function() {
    SaveAnswer('13242', '1', window.event.target.value);
  });
} else {
  textBox.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    SaveAnswer('13242', '1', this.value);
  }, false);
}
```

PS: I Think Victor is right too, `txtAnswer` isn't the actual ID of your node.

Comment: The code looks right, but it doesn't execute. I put a breakpoint on the var = textBox line and it never gets there. How do I associate this code with the text box?

Comment: run this code after the document has loaded (ex. place the `<script>` tag at the end of the body). Any element has a method `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`, in your code you where appending the event to the document, but you can append it directly to your element.